# How to retrieve Facebook user profile unique url/id

Tags: mysql, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I am planning to have a competition as a first promo for my page.
I will be using PHP for scripting.
I will uploading the scripts to a web hosting server and call the page url on FB.
On FB, I will creating unique woobox app. I will call this page on that app.

What I need on is, when the participant is given the page he/she can participate, the programe should first check if this user has already participated or not in the competition.
If he has **already participated**, he should be directed to a page where it will say, u have already participated. 
**If not** he/she should be directed to the page he will give his Name, Country & email.
On this page too, I prefer to make use of Facebook api to get the Name, Country, & email id instead of asking participants type in these info..and also get the user profile id and save in the db base, do avoid duplicate enteries

I am totally blank about this FB api n graphs...

Need you fullest help on this.. pls...

Comment: Have you added any of Facebook's sdk's to your site, if so which did you add?

Answer (score 0):

The registration plugin can grab a users info and allow them to register, the plugin will post that registration info to which ever page "database" you need.

refer to: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/